# Are there any tools which convert all fields to properties in a group of .cs files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, roslyn

Is there a tool which will convert fields to properties?

I have many fields in my project and it is taking a long time to manually convert all of the fields to properties.

Comment: Are you using `public PropertyName { get; set; }` syntax? That doesn't take long to write.

Comment: Why create the fields at all, just use Auto Properties instead, do `public bool Foo { get; set; }`

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you're doing this? My project VSDiagnostics (https://github.com/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics) has a code fix that changes non-const/static public/internal fields to properties. Analyzer implementation: https://github.com/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/blob/develop/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/VSDiagnostics/Diagnostics/General/NonEncapsulatedOrMutableField/NonEncapsulatedOrMutableFieldAnalyzer.cs

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Visual studio code snippets to generate code for you.

Just type  **prop** and press TAB, 
it will create skeleton for you. You just have to provide the name and type of the property. So simple.

Comment: That creates a new property -- it does not use any info from the existing fields.

Answer (score 0):

Built in you have [T4 Text Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx).  I typically just use XSLT or a console app when I want to generate code files.  You can also get tools like [resharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) to do more complex refactoring than is available out of the box.  Built in you will find [Encapsulate Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a5adyhe9.aspx) refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with roslyn api.you can build a tiny c# application , add roslyn api to it, open your winform and asp.net project with roslyn and do something like this you want.

First create class that get your files and return new file.

```
public class FieldToPropertyConverter: CSharpSyntaxRewriter
{
 FieldToPropertyConverter(string YourSolutionFilePath)
{
    OpenSolution( YourSolutionFilePath);
}
public void OpenSolution(string path)
{
    // OPEN your solution here
}
public Solution s ;
public void Convent()
{
     foreach ( var p in s.Projects)
         foreach ( var d in p.Documents)
         {
              var cus = Visit(d.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result);
              // save cus to solution
         }
         // save you set solution to your work space
}
public override SyntaxNode VisitFieldDeclarationSyntax( FieldDeclarationSyntax f)
{
     PropertyDeclaractionSyntax p =SyntaxFactory.PropertyDeclaraction( f.Declaraction.Type, f.Declaraction.Variables.First().Identifier);
    return p;
} 
}
```

You can use this class  like this

```
 FieldToPropertyConverter c = new FieldToPropertyConverter("solutionFilePath");
c.Convent();
c.Save();
```